# Content Injection of Attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm trying to understand how to use the new [content injection](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/content-injection) feature of Fullcalendar.

I'd like to modify the outermost `<a>` or `<div>` of an event to add attributes to enable a bootstrap popover. I see how to return new content within an event, but what is the proper way to modify an existing tag? Is that possible?